# Expose LWC in Mobile App

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-web-components

I am trying to add a custom LWC to a phone record page however getting the below error message. Could anyone help me out how to make the component mobile view-able.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation of [Form Factors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_form_factors),

> If you don’t define , the component supports the
>   form factors that the page type supports. However, we recommend
>   defining  for each page type.
>
> App pages support the Large and Small form factors. Record and Home
>   pages support only the Large form factor.
>
> Components on app pages can render on both phone and desktop because
>   the app page supports both phone and desktop. Components on record and
>   Home pages can render only on desktop because these page types support
>   only desktop.

However, record and home pages are supported from Winter'20 - `October 14, 2019` to be precise - you can refer to [Customize Lightning Record Pages for the Phone Form Factor](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_record_pages_on_mobile.htm) and [Unlock Mobile Configuration Options in the Lightning App Builder](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_mobile_app_new_enable.htm)

You can configure for phone as below: ([Form Factors documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_form_factors))

```
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__AppPage">
        <property name="prop2" type="Boolean" />
        <supportedFormFactors>
            <supportedFormFactor type="Small" />
        </supportedFormFactors>
    </targetConfig>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
        <property name="prop1" type="String" />
        <supportedFormFactors>
            <supportedFormFactor type="Large" />
        </supportedFormFactors>
    </targetConfig>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning_HomePage">
        <property name="prop3" type="Integer" />
        <supportedFormFactors>
            <supportedFormFactor type="Large" />
        </supportedFormFactors>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I have a better understanding now.